# Interesting loop? How can a base class include a child class as a member?

Tags: objective-c, logic, member, superclass

How can a base class include a child class as a member? For example:

```
@interface Magic : NSObject {
@private
       NSString* name;
       int power;
       int manaCost;
       SpecialKindOfMagic* thisMuch;
}
@end

@interface SpecialKindOfMagic : Magic {
@private
       int thisMuchSpecial;
}
@end
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? A base class should have _no knowledge_ of anything that derives it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a forward declaration before the declaration of the Magic class:

```
@class SpecialKindOfMagic;

@interface Magic ...
```

Also, it's very unusual to declare a class that doesn't descend from NSObject, so you probably meant to write:

```
@interface Magic : NSObject {
```